# How to Call a function that execute on a DIV using PHP function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

This my code :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["add"]))
    {
?>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var i=0;

    function createDiv()
    {
        $('#newdiv').append('<div id="div"'+i+'" class="ex" style="text-align: left;">Life Really suck</div>');

       i++;

       $( ".ex" ).draggable({containment:'parent',cursor:'pointer',opacity:0.6});
       $( ".ex" ).droppable();

    }

    createDiv(); // will execute when it loads this line
</script>

<?php
    }   
?>

<div id = "newdiv">    </div>
```

How can I make the function execute in the DIV outside of the condition statement?

I need the function execute normally is the GET["add"] is set

Now I it does not execute in the DIV even though the function does run

Comment: Can you please edit your message to correct typo and make it more clear ? I don't understand the problem nor what you want to do

Comment: I just want to append to the DIV, it doesn't work

Comment: It's Normal,You want to Append a content on a div, but your div don't exist, Create your div in Javascript, or, before your function.

Comment: I want to create it outside of the condition statement, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, Just Place your '<div id="newdiv"></div>' before your Php code in your page. ( and read other answer, your Jquery function isn't correct ^^ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surround your createDiv() call by `$(document).ready(function(){`  and `})`, this will execute what's inside only after the page is fully loaded.